# UI - Consuming different microservices API and consolidate the list into grid view and allow users to sort the data

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, architecture, frontend, microservices

Currently in our front end project (AngularJS), we need to consume different endpoints that are built in microservices architecture and show the data in the list view. Then we need to allow users to sort the data based on the columns selected by user. For eg, we are listing 10 columns out of which 6 are rendered from Service A and other 4 columns are pulled from another Service B. Both the services don't have direct relation mapping instead based on the object id Service B returns the data.

Now we have consolidated the list and shown the columns and allowed users to choose columns of their choice. As a next step, we need to allow users to sort any column data seamlessly. Is there any best practice followed in microservices paradigm to retrieve the data from both the services and sort them and show the result.

We have few options like

1. list all the data at once from both the services and sort the data in frontend. But problem with this approach is, if there are more dataset then user might feel slowness and at times browser can get hanged. We are using AngularJs in our project and already facing slowness when data set grows.
2. Introduce an intermediate API service(light weight nodejs server) which will helps to coordinate the request and it internally handles requesting data between different services and sends the result back.
3. Create an intermediate API service which will cache the data and orchestrates the request and responds the data from multiple services.

Can any one just share any other practices can be followed for the above use case?  In current microservices trends, all API services are exposed as separate service and it makes frontend world a bit complex to handle services between different APIs and show data to users in UI to interact.

Any suggestions or approaches or hint will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.
Srini

Comment: [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) performs well with large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, there are a few ways to handle the scenario you have. In my opinion the best approach would be option two. It is similar to the [Gateway Aggregation Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/gateway-aggregation) where you introduce a gateway layer to handle the aggregation of your service APIs. The added benefit is that you may be able to park some common functionalities in this gateway layer if required.

Of course, the obvious drawback would be that you now have another layer that needs to be highly available and managed. So do consider the pros and cons carefully before deciding on your approach. For example, if this is the only aggregation that you will ever need, then 3 may be a better option.